# Need pattern background and over it need to place an image

Tags: android

I have a pattern-based background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

On this activity I'm displaying a background-pattern:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    >
</LinearLayout
```

Have a result like: 
http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/2257/63411225.jpg

Need result:
http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/4894/12572985.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the necessary code (the layout that has both your background, and the image).

The problem has nothing to do with your background, and (probably) everything to do with how you are actually laying out your image.

If this is you complete code, you need to add a  attribute, which would include you Image.

Comment: I need to add image like it is a background. I mean pattern + image = background for activity.

Comment: In your layout file, add this attribute to your main view (LinearLayout or whatever):  android:background="@drawable/your_background"